# Design Pattern for getting data from optional services

Tags: design-patterns

In my project there are two different modules (A and B). Also module B is optional. However there is a functionality in module A to get data from module B, **only if module B is installed**.

Is there any design pattern for this scenario rather than disabling the functionality by looking at the existence of module B ??

Comment: what do you mean by word 'installed' in 'if module B is installed' ?? And you refer a method of A using the word 'functionality in module A' ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the design pattern is polymorphism. Make module `A` abstract and create two subclasses.

1. `A1` always uses `B`.
2. `A2` never uses `B`.

Common logic remains in `A`. At runtime, check once for the existence of `B` and then inject the appropriate subclass of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce an API for Module B with an actual implementation and a [null pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern/) implementation. While wiring your application you can choose which one to use, depending on availability of Module B.

The Null pattern implementation should behave so that module A is unaware whether Module B is there or not.